# HTTPOnly Cookie not being stored before redirect

Tags: cookies, http-headers, httprequest, httponly, cookie-httponly

Currently, I have an HTML page that sends a POST request to a Python server with login details. The Python server verifies the login and then sends back a cookie via headers (I'm using the Cookie class built into the Python library). I want to redirect as soon as I get a 200 OK status. The issue is that the cookies are not being set quickly enough, so the redirect happens before the cookies are set and thus the check_login page will display that I have not logged in.

I want the browser to store an HTTPOnly cookie. Is there something in the XMLHttpRequest API that will let me redirect after the cookie has been stored, or an alternative method?

Thanks!

The HTTPRequest code:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://localhost/login/';
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
    if(httpRequest.status == 200) {
      window.location = "http://localhost/check_login/";
    }
}; 
httpRequest.open("POST", url,false);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.send(/*login details*/);
```

This request is called by clicking a button. If I go back to the page that this button is on and then click it again, I will always be logged in because the cookie was already set from the first click.